# AppFabric Cache Server replication

Tags: c#, architecture, appfabric, specifications, distributed-caching

After some googling around I have found not a lot on the question I am about to ask.

Is it possible to have the AppFabric replicate the cache across different servers? (Like shared cache says it can..).

I am trying to spec out a new app with the possibility of a distributed cache down the line, but obviously knowing now what we can and can't do would help that.

Having a cache cluster isn't an option at the moment, so simply having all the server aware of each other cache would be a major benefit (for redundancy also).

Also - on a site note, would you have to specify each server individually on a web.config basis? Or just reference 'a cluster'.

I know there is a replication port - but nothing about anything on the internets!

Any help would be mucho appreciated!

Comment: Thats how AppFabric works, MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790954.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. "secondaries" parameter.

Have a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790974.aspx).